# WiX minor upgrade remove Windows 7 taskbar pinned shortcut

Tags: wix

Every update to new version WiX for some reason removed pinned start menu shortcut from taskbar. How can I fix this?

Shortcut was created using this command:

```
   <DirectoryRef Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Component Id="GitExtensions.newstartmenu" Guid="*">
        <Shortcut
          Id="GitExtensions.newstartmenu"
          Name="$(var.ProductName)"
          Description="$(var.ProductName)"
          Icon="gitextensions.ico"
          Target="[INSTALLDIR]GitExtensions.exe"
          WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"/>
        <RegistryValue
          Root="HKCU" Key="$(var.InstalledRegKey)"
          Name="GitExtensions.newstartmenu" Value="" Type="string"
          KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

WiX code: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/blob/f9490e3e6e34cc2f6770fd9e1d6132cf5cfd0b0b/Setup/Product.wxs#L385-L399

Setup had been built in VS2010 + WiX 3.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually doing a [major upgrade](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/blob/master/Setup/EnableUpgrades.wxi) and by scheduling RemoveExistingProducts early, the upgrade is removing the older version before installing the newer version. The shell removes the pin when the older shortcut is removed. You can try experimenting with a later scheduling of RemoveExistingProducts but note that there are [costs associated](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/12/30/paying-for-upgrades/) with that.

Comment: Is it still experimental or is there something new in WiX 3.8 or 3.9 to keep the existing taskbar icon? If not, could you develop a bit more on what would be needed to do?

Comment: @BobArnson In your blog post, it sounds as if the "cost" of scheduling RemoveExistingProducts later is the upgrade can _never_ remove any files that were present in an earlier version. This passage implies that's true even for "major upgrades": _'you can avoid the costs of minor upgrades by simply using major upgrades. You can remove files ... if you use an “early” scheduling of the RemoveExistingProducts standard action.'_ If so, does it mean it's 100% impossible to have an upgrade that both (a) removes some files from an old version, and (b) doesn't break the user's pinned Taskbar entries?